# Image will not center in my email. Using div. CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, email, alignment

I'm creating a responsive email... and tested it out on mail chimp and it was fine all throughout. but when tested on exact target (the email client needed to send out this email) 
the image I need to center near bottom of email... WILL not center. see code:

```
  <div class="layout one-col fixed-width" style=
  "Margin: 0 auto;max-width: 600px;min-width: 320px; width: 320px;width: calc(28000% -167400px);overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-word;">
  <div class="layout__inner" style=
  "border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color: #f8f6f6;"
  margin-left:="" emb-background-style="">
      <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"><tr class="layout-fixed-width" emb-background-style><td style="width: 600px" class="w560"><![endif]-->

      <div class="column" style=
      "text-align: center; position: absolute !important; color: #8e8e8e;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;font-family: Cabin,Avenir,sans-serif;max-width: 600px;min-width: 320px; width: 320px;width: calc(28000% -167400px);">
      <div style=
      "Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;Margin-bottom: 15px;font-size: 12px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;"
        align="center">
          <a href="url"
          target="_blank"></a>

          <center>
            <img style=
            "Margin-top: 10px; Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;Margin-bottom: 15px;border: 0;display: block; text-align: center; position: absolute !important;height: auto;width: 100%;max-width: 257px;"
            alt="Partnerships" src="image7_1112017.png" />
          </center>
        </div>
      </div><!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Everything else seems to be fine... but this is the only image that needs to be centered. fyi i got got the template from campaign monitor and modified accordingly. image was not centered in template.

Comment: You should use `table`, most of the properties like `margin`, `display` etc won't work in most of the email clients.

Comment: any chance you could give me a sample code or modified code for this section? i've already used divs for the entire email. as i used a template.

Comment: never mind. it worked!!! thank you so much for this!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the width of a block-level element will stop it from filling the width of its container. Taking advantage of this you can set the margin to automatically split the remaining space evenly on the left and right side.

```
<div style="width: 200px; margin: auto;">
    <img alt="Partnerships" src="image7_1112017.png" style="width: 100%;" />
</div>
```

Here we set the image container width to 200px and the image to 100% so it will scale to the width given. So even if an image is 500px wide, it will be centered and scaled down to 200px because that is the defined size of the container. If you know the width of your image, assign that to the container then setting the image element width becomes unnecessary.

**EDIT**

You may want to consider reformatting the body of your html. You will want to remove `display:table;` from the container with the `layout__inner` class.

```
<body>
    <div class="layout one-col fixed-width" style="max-width: 600px;min-width: 320px;">
         <div class="layout__inner" style="background-color: #f8f6f6;">
            <!-- Content Body -->
            <div style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                Here is some example content. This is where you want your main content to be.
            </div>
            <!-- /Content Body -->
            <div style="width:200px;margin:auto;">
                <img alt="Partnerships" src="image7_1112017.png" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seanclendening/3ogc8rxk/)

Comment: I've tried the suggestions but it just doesn't seem to budge. i am not sure why that is?? I've tried various methods but it stubbornly remains to be aligned left no matter what i do!

Comment: I updated my response, you will want to remove the table display style property as seen in the example

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a one column one row table (maybe). You have a lot of divs in your code, way too many. And also a lot of CSS that won't work in an email. Keep the CSS simple, use tables to center things. Use a lot of nested tables rather than one table with many rows and columns. Try this in your DIV. It may work, but you may have to rework the  rest of your code too.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">

           <img 
            alt="Partnerships" src="image7_1112017.png" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 15px;border: 0;" /></td>
        </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```